# Any suggestions on why when I deploy to physical android content wont display?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

It works find in iOS and Android emulator.

Sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyViewPage"
             Visual="Material" Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10">
            <Label Text="MyLabel" FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <WebView HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000" Source="{Binding BasicsContent}"></WebView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The Code

```
public partial class MyViewPage: ContentPage
    {
        public MyViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MyPageViewModel();
        }
    }
```

This is an example from a page I created with very little content. Any suggestions on how to debug this or test with specific controls?

Comment: Do you mean no content displays?  Or the webview content doesn't display?  Did you check the console for any relevant messages?  Is the content local or a remote url?

Comment: Neither, on another page I just have two labels and no webview same issue. Nothing in the console and all content is local.

Answer (score 0):

So my labels dont specify a TextColor. For some reason the emulator shows fine. Well on device the text color is white and not black (like the emulators). The two screens I do specify color and one section shows correct. The images load but....

So in app.xaml I added

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Seems that you have solved your problem by assigning style?

Comment: Styles then I found out one device was in dark mode and another in light. Wow, so much to learn in this mobile space.